# Using sqlite in thread that runs from alarmmanager

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite, alarmmanager

I want to create a simple Service (based on the ApiDemos\app\AlarmService_Service example)
In the service's thread I want to add a record to a local DB every 15Sec.

But the problem is that the DataSource I created (with the help of http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html article) needs `Context` object in order to initiate the DataSource.

In the near future I'll want a service like this example to run also when the device booted.
So my qustion is how can I use sqlite in situation where I have no Context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my qustion is how can I use sqlite in situation where I have no Context?

`Service` inherits from `Context`, and so you have a `Context`. Bear in mind that you need to have a singleton `SQLiteOpenHelper` (or `SQLiteDatabase`) if you expect other threads to also be using the database.

BTW, that sample is quite possibly the worst Google has ever published. I am not completely clear on why the user wants you to "add a record to a local DB every 15Sec" in the background, but that sample:

- will fail to keep the device awake
- displays a `Notification` for no particular reason
- has you roll your own thread rather than using `IntentService` which handles that for you
- does not handle multiple commands sent to the service
- has a largely pointless `Binder`
- etc.

The proper way to use `AlarmManager` with `_WAKEUP` alarms is either to use [my `WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) or [the Android Support package's `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html).
I have published [a sample using `WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/Wakeful) with `AlarmManager` and [an equivalent sample using `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/WakeCast).